# Use ajax to pre-load a page in a Rails app and then display it within the main layout

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I have a simple application that is currently working, but I am trying to convert it to use ajax in order to improve the user experience so that full page reloads are not required every time a user clicks a link in the navigation. It uses a simple Header / Body / Footer approach with the nav bar included inside the header.

So currently, when I click on any of my nav items, it correctly changes the active-state CSS highlight properly, which I have done using Coffeescript.

As you will see in the code below, my 4th link in the navigation links to "new_movie_path". This page uses Nokogiri to crawl a web site (for example IMDB.com) and displays the current Box Office Top 10 movies, so it is something that can take a few moments to do and does not load instantly. This module individually is working just fine.

What I am trying to do is make it so that when I click on that link, it doesn't refresh the page, but instead, fetches the data using an ajax call and shows the result within the body of my current layout. I have added the ***remote: true*** element to the link but after much trial and error have failed to figure out the rest. Bonus: A spinner appears while the data is being loaded.

Snippets from my existing code:

**/app/views/layout/application.erb.html**

```
<body>
  <%= render 'shared/header' %>
  <div class="container first-contain" id="body-content">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</body>
```

**/app/views/shared/_header.html.erb**

```
<ul class="nav">          
  <li class="active"><%= link_to "Home", "#" %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "About", "#" %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Contact", "#" %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "New Movies", new_movie_path, remote: true %></li>
</ul>
```

**/app/assets/javascripts/navigation.js.coffee**

```
$ ->
  changeTab = (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    $("ul.nav li.active").removeClass "active"
    $(@).addClass("active")
  $("ul.nav li").click changeTab
```

Any help in this matter is much appreciated.

Comment: if i understood your question correctly - then any kind of ajax technology is your friend. I would recommend pjax, because of easy installation and customization. There is always gem for rails.

Comment: Thanks. I definitely think pjax is a good option. I was hoping to learn how to do it the old fashioned way just for information's sake. For those interested in pjax, Ryan Bates has a great tutorial: http://railscasts.com/episodes/294-playing-with-pjax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another file to handle the AJAX request. Suppose that movies link takes you to the 'show' action, then you would have a `movies/show.js.erb` view template file.

Let's say the action crawls IMDB and populates an array of names of movies in `@movies`

Your view file might then look like this:

```
<% 
  if @movies
    out = ''
    @movies.each do |m|
      out += m + '\n'
    end
%>
$("#body").html('<%= out %>');
<% end %>
```

This assumes you're using jquery ofcourse (and you should be). Essentially, you have to, one way or another, use javascript to replace the contents of your HTML body.

Answer (score 0):

The ajax request should send you to `MoviesController#new` which is already working as you've said.  You need to add a new view called `new.js.erb` under `app/views/movies` which will contain the javascript that you want to run after the request finishes ie

```
# movies_controller.rb
def new
  @movies = parse_movies_from_imdb
end

# new.js.erb
<% @movies.each do |movie| %>
  console.log(movie);
<% end %>
```

Comment: My question was 'how do I make that ajax request?'. You breezed through that part entirely :/

Comment: I thought you knew what you were doing when you added `remote: true` to the link.  That is basically sending an ajax request to the controller.